# C# CommandLineApplication Console App to read an appsettings.json file

Tags: c#, json, json.net, console-application

Is there a way in C# to let a Console App to read a json file ??

appsettings.json

```
   {
       "Position": {
            "Title": "Editor",
            "Name": "Joe Smith"
       }
   }
```

program.cs (snippets)

```
 public static int Main(string[] args)
 {
     var application = new CommandLineApplication<Program>();
     application.Conventions.UseDefaultConventions();
     // something like application.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

     return application.Execute(args);
 }
```

Then in the apps OnExecute function

```
 protected void OnExecute() {
    string arg1 = jsonSettings("Position:Title");
    Console.WriteLine(arg1);
 }
```

The variable would set the variable and output "Editor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, it should work *with some tweaks* ;)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Setup Host
        var host = CreateDefaultBuilder().Build();
            
        // Invoke Worker
        using (IServiceScope serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            IServiceProvider provider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
            var fooService = provider.GetRequiredService<FooService>();
            ...
        }

        host.Run();
    }
    
    static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(app =>
            {
                app.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<FooService>();
            });
    }
}
```

You'll need to add the nuget package "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" and go to the appsettings file properties and set "copy to output directory" to "always"

Working example can be found here: [JsonSettingsConsleApplication](https://github.com/jloucaosilva/JSonSettingsConsoleApp)

Comment: cool, thanks, I dont understand where you have the "using IServiceLine" half way through the Main function ? this errors Also you have removed the CommandLineApplication code, required to run the app :)

Comment: @WelshKing just updated the answer, see if you can use it now.
The using IServiceScope comes from the new using and nuget package I now mention, as for the CommandLineApplicationCode, I can use as it is

Comment: @WelshKing also added a link to a repository with a working example

Answer (score 0):

Within your application you have to add those two packages:

- [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder)
- [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json)

Afterwards you have to setup the read of the file into a configuration object:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
```

And then read the configuration into a matching object:

```
var section = config.GetSection(nameof(WeatherClientConfig));
var weatherClientConfig = section.Get<WeatherClientConfig>();
```

These code example with more details can be found [here](https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-read-custom-configuration-from-appsettings-json/).